# Cypher Query to Collect Arbitrary Depth Nodes and Edge Properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that looks like the image below. However, the depth and the number of rollups from the Person to the topmost Rollup is variable depending on how the rollups have been structured by the user. The edges from the Person to the Metric (HAS_METRIC) have the score values and the relationships from the metrics to the Rollup (HAS_PARENT) has the weighting that should be applied by to the value as it is rolled up to a top score.

[image: graph]

Ideally, I would like to have a query that produces a table with the rollup and the summed/weighted scores. Like this:

```
    node    |  value
 -------------------
   Metric A    23
   Metric B    55
   Metric C    29
   Metric D    78
   Rollup A    45.4
   Rollup B    58.4
   Rollup Tot  51.9
```

However, I am not understanding how to collect the edge properties for the HAS_PARENTS.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[score:HAS_METRIC]->(m:Metric)-[weight:HAS_PARENT]->(ru:Rollup)
        -[par_rel:HAS_PARENT*..8]->(ru_par:Rollup)
WITH p, score, m, weight, par_rel, ru, ru_par
RETURN p.uid, score.score, m.uid, weight.weight, ru.uid par_rel.weight, ru_par.uid
```

This query is giving me a type mismatch because it does not know what to do with the par_rel.weight. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: FYI: Your image and table do not have the same value for `Metric D`.

Comment: Thanks I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are searching for is the `relationships(path)` function. It is one of the default path functions in Cypher. It returns all relationship is a defined *path*, and you can combine it with one or more Cypher *list expressions* to get the values you need from the relationships.

Generally speaking, you could do something like:

```
MATCH p = (n)-[:HAS_PARENT*..8]->()
RETURN [x IN relationships(p) | x.weight] AS weights
```

You might also find useful the `reduce` function. E.g.:

```
...
RETURN reduce(s = 0, x IN relationships(p) | s + x.weight) AS sumWeight
```

But you need to be careful with your *variable length path* queries and probably constrain them in order to get only the paths you are interested in.

A good advice would be probably to mark your leaf and root nodes in order to match only paths from a leaf to a/the root, not just intermediate ones. E.g.:

```
MATCH p = (n)-[:HAS_PARENT*..8]->(root)
WHERE NOT (root)-[:HAS_PARENT]->() AND NOT (n)<-[:HAS_PARENT]-()
...
```

And of course you can combine these cypher with others in order to return everything you need in one single query.

I hope this helps. Let us know when you succeed.

Comment: A combination of these techniques ended up working for me to implement the calculations. I was not able to get it in one query, although I suspect someone with more knowledge could. I ended up getting the structure (top and bottom) of the hierarchy with one query and using another to get the values based on that structure.